# Tailwind absolute position isn't working in Safari and all mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Can't understand the problem with Tailwind.

Positioning problem: in the mobile version of the browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) + desktop version of safari - the top menu moves to the right. Although absolute positioning is set to right - 0

Desktop Safari + on all mobile browsers. Proof:

[image]

An additional oddity is that the same element, but set to left - 0, works fine.

In a desktop browser (Firefox / Chrome) - everything works properly.
Proof:

[image]

In safari, as I pointed out, the same error occurs.

My component HTML:

```
return (
    <div
      ref={wrapperRef}
      onClick={handleClick}
      className="relative flex w-fit cursor-pointer"
    >
      {children}
      <div
        ref={menuRef}
        className={`absolute ${!isActive ? "hidden" : ""}
      
          ${topRight ? "bottom-full right-0" : ""}
          ${topLeft ? "left-0 bottom-full" : ""}
          ${bottomRight ? "right-0 top-full" : ""}
          ${bottomLeft ? "left-0 top-full" : ""}
      
          z-20 my-[8px] flex min-w-[112px] max-w-[280px] flex-col`}
      >
        <div
          className={`flex max-h-[310px] min-w-max flex-col ${overflow} animate-fade-in rounded-[8px] bg-indigo-50 py-[8px] shadow-mm-1 dark:bg-gray-800`}
        >
          {menu}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Menu item HTML:

```
return (
    <div onClick={onClick} className="flex items-start" key={id}>
      <div className="flex h-[48px] w-full cursor-pointer items-center justify-center bg-indigo-50 pl-[12px] pr-[24px] text-label-large text-black hover:bg-indigo-100 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white hover:dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white">
        <div className={`${leftElement && "pr-[12px] text-gray-500"}`}>
          {leftElement}
        </div>
        <p className="flex w-full">{label || children}</p>
        <div
          className={`${
            rightElement && "min-w-max pl-[28px] text-body-small text-gray-500"
          }`}
        >
          {rightElement}
        </div>
        <div className={`${badge && "pl-[28px] text-gray-500"}`}>
          {badge && <Badge text={badgeText || "New"} />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Who can tell what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try just applying your styles in a simple string instead of template literals to see if something isn't detected correctly in the building process?
That's my best guess right now, because I tried to quickly replicate your issue with the tailwind playground and I can't see your bug there: https://play.tailwindcss.com/MmnwqXYCV1

Comment: You saw I attached a gif, there is no problem at first glance.

But I solved it, as it turned out (I don't know why), I had to change the width settings of the containers of all elements. While everything worked well in chrome and ff, it also worked in safari. It turns out that there was a snag in this, browsers read the same settings in different ways and they need to be optimized somehow.

Comment: Could you please post what you needed to do? What width settings did you need to change - are you using different width settings in Safari vs Chrome?